# TypeScript AngularJS component modal - this.$modalInstance.dismiss is not a function?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've turned one of my user data entry forms into a uib-modal, but I get when I attempt to close the modal from the "cancel"button, I get this error: `this.$modalInstance.dismiss is not a function.` . Same thing is if use `this.modalInstance.close().`  Which is weird because TypeScript seems to think those methods should be there based on the code completion in VS Code.

Anyway, the basic set up is as follows:

Controller which opens the modal:

```
class TestModalController {

    static $inject = ['$modal'];
    options: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalSettings;
    myModal? : ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalInstanceService;

    constructor(private $modal: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalService) {

        this.options = {
            animation: true,
            component: 'fringeEdit',
            windowClass: 'fringe-edit',
            resolve: {}
        }
    }

    openFringeEdit() {
        this.myModal = this.$modal.open(this.options);
    }
}
```

This works fine, the modal opens as expected.

This is the modal instance itself:

```
class FringeEditController {

    static $inject =['$uibModalInstance']
    constructor(private $uibModalInstance: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalInstanceService) {

    }

    dismiss() {
      this.$uibModalInstance.close("closed");  //This throws error whether using dismiss or close
    }

}
```

Registration Code:

```
app.controller("FringeEditController",['$uibModalInstance', FringeEditController]);
app.controller("TestModalController", ['$uibModal', TestModalController]);

app.component("fringeEdit", {
    controller: "FringeEditController",
    templateUrl: "/template/fringeEditTemplate.html",
    bindings: {}
});
```

I've tried several tweaks from various posts here, but I keep getting this error, which leads me to believe that whatever is being passed in as as $uibModalInstance isn't actually a $uibModalInstance, otherwise close and dismiss would work, wouldn't it?

Not really sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `component` property of the `$uibModal.open` method, use bindings instead of local injection:

```
app.component("fringeEdit", {
    controller: "FringeEditController",
    templateUrl: "/template/fringeEditTemplate.html",
    bindings: { close: "&" }
});
```

Then use the bindings in the controller:

```
dismiss() {
  this.close({$value: "closed"});
}
```

From the Docs:

> ## $uibModal's open function
>
> ### options parameter
>
> - `component (Type: string, Example: myComponent)` - A string reference to the component to be rendered that is registered with Angular's compiler. If using a directive, the directive must have restrict: 'E' and a template or templateUrl set.
>
>   It supports these bindings:
>
>   - `close` - A method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result. The result must be passed in this format: `{$value: myResult}`

For more information, see

- [UI-Bootstrap Modal Directive API Reference](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!modal)

Comment: Not quite working.  I made the changes you suggested but tyepScript compiler complains that "Property 'close' does not exist on type 'FringeEditController'.  Function bindings are confusing for me in t/ypescript, don't understand  how the compiler is meant to know that "close(...)" is  defined on the class through the binding with?

Comment: Resolved here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516708/confused-by-adaptation-of-angularjs-component-based-modal-to-typescript)